# got stuck with this set of code in jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
var formRules  = $(this).data('rules');
var formValues = $(this).data('values');

    if(formRules || formValues){
        var rulesArray = formRules.split(',');
        var valuesArray = formValues.split(',');
        for(var i=0; i < rulesArray.length; i++){
            //alert(rulesArray[i]);
            $.validationEngine.defaults.rulesArray[i] = valuesArray[i];
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

This throws an error like following

```
Error: TypeError: $.validationEngine.defaults.rulesArray is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:8380/javascript/jquery.validationEngine.js
Line: 2092
```

I cannot find the problem with this code.Any help is welcome

EDIT:

I am trying to set the global options `eg:scroll` using the for loop.
The `formRules` string will have these options comma seperated and the corresponding values in the `formValues` string.

So i am expecting it to come like `$.validationEngine.defaults.scroll = true;`

Comment: `$.validationEngine.defaults.rulesArray` is undefined. Not sure how to break it down any further. Are you sure you have the variable name right?

Comment: validationEngine looks to be a jquery extension and you might be missing it. Is it something like this: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line

```
 $.validationEngine.defaults.rulesArray[i] = valuesArray[i];
```

to this

```
 $.validationEngine.defaults[rulesArray[i]] = valuesArray[i];
```

rulesArray is not a child of $.validationEngine.defaults. The values stored in your rulesArray are. The syntax in my second code block references everything properly.

This is called **Bracket Notation**, a way to get an object's property using any sort of valid calculation *(like rulesArray[i], or "myStringPropertyName")*. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators for other methods.

Comment: It pretty much solved the issue i asked here, but it failed to achieve my objective. I think  i will have to device another idea for this :). The problem is the values should be boolean true/false, but here it is treated as string.

Comment: If i have more than one form in a url, the second form's rules override the first form's rules. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @zamil I am not, yet, a jquery validation expert. But this SO answer has some interesting input on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/a/15815040/2646455. If your validation rules apply to specific forms, rather than globally applied, this should resolve your problem.